# PowerShell Replace Regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have a `select-string` which is searching an IIS log for a particular string and returning the 2 lines above and one line below.

Results look like this:

```
2012-06-15 18:26:09 98.138.206.39 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB10 - 25 - - 220+mta1083.sbc.mail.ne1.yahoo.com+ESMTP+YSmtp+service+ready 0 0 60 0 218 SMTP - - - -
2012-06-15 18:26:09 98.138.206.39 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB10 - 25 EHLO - WEB10.DOMAIN>COM 0 0 4 0 218 SMTP - - - -
> 2012-06-15 18:26:09 74.125.244.10 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB10 - 25 - - 550+IP+Authorization+check+failed+-+psmtp 0 0 41 0 218 SMTP - - - -
2012-06-15 18:26:09 74.125.244.10 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB10 - 25 RSET - - 0 0 4 0 218 SMTP - - - -
```

Note the third line begins with `>` denoting that's the line that `select-string` matched upon.

I am trying to do a `-replace` on the `>` to replace it with `< font color="red">$1< /font>` but my replace doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
$results = $results -replace "(^> )(.*)$", "< font color='red'>$1< font>"
```

Can any PowerShell regex gurus out there tell me why my regular expression isn't matching?

Comment: Code: $list = gci $log_location -include "ex*.log" | where { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $yesterday} 
$results = cat $list | select-string -pattern $error_codes -Context $num_lines_before,$num_lines_after | Foreach { $_.Context.PreContext "<font color='red'>$($_.Line)</font>" $_.Context.PostContext} | sort value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start thinking-object rather than text, because what you see is only formated object, not actual output of select-string.
Instead of parsing this output - use objects that you get (Get-Member will let you discover them).

I guess this should do what you need:

```
# Prepare test data...
$tring = @'
alfa
beta
gamma
delta
alfa
beta
alfa
beta
'@.Split("`n")

# Display results with actually matching line highlighted in red...
"<body>"
$tring | select-string 'delta' -Context 2,2 | foreach {
    $_.Context.PreContext
    "<font color='red'>$($_.Line)<font>"
    $_.Context.PostContext
}
"</body>"
```

HTH
Bartek

Comment: This makes sense but powershell is choking on something: Unexpected token '<font color=`'red`'>$($_.Line)</font>' in expression or statement. I've tried escaping the single quotes, the angle brackets, everything I can think of. I even removed all special characters and it still gags. I'm not sure why its angry.

Comment: Strange... can you post whole code you are using? It looks like you are missing newline somewhere... Also, to make sure both statements are separated you can use semicolon between the two.

Comment: Just to be sure you *have* seperated three statements in foreach-object (and your error suggest otherwise) - please separate them with semicolons and try than: foreach { $_.Context.PreContext; "<font color='red'>$($_.Line)</font>"; $_.Context.PostContext }

Comment: Semi-colons - that was the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If $a contains the value of your third line try :

```
$a -replace '(^>)(.*)','font color="red">$2<font/>'
```

Two things :

1. Use single qutes for your RegEx
2. The index of groups begin at 1

Comment: My script runs with the code above but it doesn't actually do a replace because its not matching anything :-\